# How to preview specific folder in email notification?

Tags: email, notifications, 4.1-jelly-bean

I have a Note 2 with Android 4.1.1 plus updates. I really like the built-in email client and I use it with my Gmail account as an exchange service. Even push mail works great with it.

However, I am subscribed to several folders. Whenever I am getting an email to one of the subscribed folders I have a notification. The problem is that when several emails arrive in different folders the notification preview always shows the first 2-3 mails from INBOX, even when the mails are in other folders. I would like to set this to "Gmail/AllMail" so that I can see in the notification preview the newly received mail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, its not possible with stock email client unless Samsung pushes an update. Try other email clients from Play Store.

Comment: This may be true, but it's not a solution. No offense intended, but I can't accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go back to the general Gmail app.  It allows you to have multiple accounts (in case that's why you were using the other built-in client).

```
Settings->Add Account
```

Labels can be set and are visible.  Lastly, since you're using Jelly Bean, you'll see similar email preview notifications - and it won't only show the first 2-3 inbox items.

Comment: Yes, I could, but I like Samsung's email client better because of the S Pen integration. Thanks for the tip though, but I can't accept it as a solution.